# Como se administran los usuarios en ASP.NET Webforms VS2015

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Buen día,
Como se administran los usuarios y roles en ASP.NET, he visto que era con membership pero ya esta descontinuado y ahora es con Identity pero lo encuentro muy confuso y se basan principalmente en MVC, el problema es que ya hay parte del sitio hecho en aspx y no en MVC.
Asi que como es la cosa con esto de los usuarios en ASP.NET

Comment: Saludos GraphicPixel, te dejo un par de enlaces: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project y https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity (este último siento que es el que buscas) Saludos y bienvenido a SOes :D

Comment: Huy fredyfx, parece ser que es justo lo que estoy buscando, en todo lo que busque entre ayer y hoy la verdad no había visto nada similar, por fin una luz diferente a los típicos tutoriales de Microsoft.
Muchas Gracias compadre!!!!

Comment: de nada mi hermano :D  te agradecería que al lograr responder tu pregunta, la publiques aquí, de tal manera que entre todos crecemos :D éxitos con el desarrollo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente y al parecer la única manera de crear usuarios y administrarlos en un sitio web asp.net es mediante el nuevo Identity, que parece estar crudo aun.
Por desgracia para mi se basa en MVC tendré que investigar si puedo usar MVC y Webforms al tiempo, sin problemas.

La respuesta a esta pregunta se encuentra en el siguiente enlace:

#### Identity Manager using ASP.NET Identity

url: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity

Comment: podrías extraer un ejemplo del enlace para que la respuesta tenga la calidad que se busca en el sitio, gracias :D